# Is a question specifically about outsourcing software development on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Is this question on-topic?

[Outsourcing some software development tasks](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/17889/outsourcing-some-software-development-tasks)

Other non-software questions that were this industry specific have been rejected in the past, if I recall correctly. It seems that this question is too narrow for workplace, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is definitely not about navigating the professional workplace. It's specifically about how to negotiate outsourcing agreements. Furthermore, the asker is looking for a list of things he/she is missing instead of asking something more specific.  Stack Exchange doesn't really work very well for "brainstorming" type questions.

If edited, such a question might work on another Stack Exchange site.